# How to find issue while installing Managed Package in Cloud CRM Dynamics 365?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2016

I am facing an issue while installing my Managed package in Cloud CRM Dynamics 365. As I am not able to track the issue, it's a headache.

Let me explain the key points:

1. I have set customizable `false` for all the components
2. I have registered Plug-in in Sandbox mode. I have used plugin registration tool for license and a few other functions.

I have tried two ways.

First: When I tried to install the first time, I got unprocess status from workflow.

Second: To solve above issue, I have tried by removing Licence process related component. Now I am getting unprocess status from Plugin Assembly of Updating Sales Order.

The worst thing is I am not getting any error message or error code in log file.

Finally, here are a few logs. Can anybody suggest a solution?

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    AsynchronousProcessingService   Failed to add the item  to the sync item collection for the mailbox : {8CBF53D0-896B-E611-80F2-FC15B4288714}. Exception details : Unhandled Exception: Microsoft.Crm.CrmArgumentException: Invalid input.

       at Microsoft.Crm.Asynchronous.EmailConnector.ExchangeItemFinder.AddItemToSyncItemChangeInfoCollection(Item item, String itemId, SyncItemChangeType itemChangeType, ItemObjectType itemObjectType, String crmId)

    Inner Exception: System.ArgumentException: Invalid input.
    AsynchronousProcessingService   Failed to add the item  to the ItemFinder sync error collection for the mailbox : {8CBF53D0-896B-E611-80F2-FC15B4288714}. Exception details : Unhandled Exception: Microsoft.Crm.CrmArgumentException: Invalid input.

       at Microsoft.Crm.Asynchronous.EmailConnector.ExchangeItemFinder.AddItemToItemFinderSyncErrors(String itemId, SyncItemChangeType itemChangeType, ItemObjectType itemObjectType, Exception ex)

    Inner Exception: System.ArgumentException: Invalid input.

  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    WebApplicationServer    MessageProcessor fail to process message 'InitializeFrom' for 'none'.

  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    WebApplicationServer    InitializeFrom cannot be invoked from source entity of type account with id 89abd2b1-248f-e611-80f3-fc15b4282658 to target entity type task because there is no entity map defined between these two entities.

  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    WebApplicationServer    Web Service Plug-in failed in SdkMessageProcessingStepId: 27cbbb1b-ea3e-db11-86a7-000a3a5473e8; EntityName: none; Stage: 30; MessageName: InitializeFrom; AssemblyName: Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.InternalOperationPlugin, Microsoft.Crm.ObjectModel, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35; ClassName: Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.InternalOperationPlugin; Exception: Unhandled Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

       at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)

       at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)

       at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)

       at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)

       at System.Web.Services.Protocols.LogicalMethodInfo.Invoke(Object target, Object[] values)

       at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.InternalOperationPlugin.Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)

       at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.V5PluginProxyStep.ExecuteInternal(PipelineExecutionContext context)

       at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.VersionedPluginProxyStepBase.Execute(PipelineExecutionContext context)

    Inner Exception: Microsoft.Crm.CrmException: There is no entity map defined for the given entities

       at Microsoft.Crm.ObjectModel.CustomizationService.InitializeFrom(BusinessEntityMoniker moniker, String targetEntityName, TargetFieldType targetFieldType, Boolean mapReadSecuredOnSourceAndTarget, ExecutionContext context)

       at Microsoft.Crm.ObjectModel.CustomizationService.InitializeFrom(BusinessEntityMoniker moniker, String targetEntityName, TargetFieldType targetFieldType, ExecutionContext context)

  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    WebApplicationServer    MessageProcessor fail to process message 'InitializeFrom' for 'none'.

  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    WebApplicationServer    MSCRM Error Report:

    Error: There is no entity map defined for the given entities
    Error Number: 0x80040E01
    Error Message: There is no entity map defined for the given entities
    Error Details: There is no entity map defined for the given entities
    Source File: Not available
    Line Number: Not available
    Request URL: 
    Stack Trace Info: [CrmException: There is no entity map defined for the given entities]
       at Microsoft.Crm.Application.Platform.ServiceCommands.PlatformCommand.XrmExecuteInternal()

       at Microsoft.Crm.Application.Platform.ServiceCommands.InitializeFromCommand.Execute()
```

Comment: I had similar issues on-premise too. Only thing that worked for me was to disassemble the solution (it was unmanaged in my case) and moving over my customizations little by little through multiple different solutions (no clue about the root cause of the broken import process...)

Comment: Have you tried to import this managed package to some organization that you have on-premise and check the Traces?

Comment: @PawelGradecki Thanks. Actually I need to configure on-premise. It might take time. However, I have tried to import in CRM Trial online blank account and it was working fine. But it is not working my old CRM which is upgraded with Cloud Dynamics 365. Is there any other method to trace in CRM Cloud(online) 365? Please guide me.

Comment: @Alex I have added error logs. Can you please suggest me?

Comment: @PawelGradecki I have added error logs. Can you please suggest me?

Comment: nothing really clear here... Is the assembly with your plugins existing in your target environment? If yes, can you try to update it using Plugin Registration Tool?

Comment: @NanjiMange You need to get in touch with MS support and ask for traces, bugs are *not as unlikely as MS would like them to be*

Comment: @PawelGradecki Thanks. I will surely try this. I got above logs when I tried to install using Package Deployer tool. I use Plugin Registration Tool for License Process and Update few parameters when Sales Order get fulfilled.

Comment: @Alex Finally I have contacted to Microsoft to get trace report. I have attached report in my question. Can you please guide me based on it.

Comment: @PawelGradecki I have tried as you suggested but didn't get rid. Finally I have contacted to Microsoft to get trace report. I have attached report in my question. Can you please guide me based on it.

Comment: Like it was suggested before - try to create a new empty solution and export/import customizations adding the components little by little, to identifiy which component is causing error. First try to import solution without plugins, if it still fails, remove other components one by one and check if at any point it will succees. Can you post a screenshot of how the error looks like when you import the solution? Most likely you removed some managed solution and it left some trash behind, you just need to identify what is this trash

Answer (score 0):

***Update**
Try turning off the plugins and workflows related to the entities and try again. Looks like you code have a bug in your plugin as well.

---

**Based on the error message's it appears TFS does not permission to save the configuration file in the user roaming path:**

`Error Message: SaveConfigToFile() - fail - \\tpapsvmgmt01\UserMyDocs\sbrown\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\PackageDeployer\Default_PackageDeployer.exe`

Also, what version of the SDK are you using? It states you are using a pre 8.0 version. Ensure you have the latest SDK dll's.

```
PackageDeployment   Information 8   4/4/2017 10:06:45 AM  Executing Solution Import Pre v8.0
Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector.CrmServiceClient    Verbose 16  4/4/2017 10:08:43 AM  Failed to Execute Command - ImportSolution
Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector.CrmServiceClient    Error   2   4/4/2017 10:08:43 AM  Source    : mscorlib
Method  : HandleReturnMessage
Date    : 4/4/2017
Time    : 10:08:43 AM
Error   : Message: Import failed
ErrorCode: -2147188706
Trace: 
Stack Trace : Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.Servic
```

Could be the configuration setting that are being used to 
Authentic because it is throwing error invoking channel proxy command.

Comment: Hi, I didn't get result even after few efforts. Finally I have contacted to Microsoft to get trace report. I have attached report in my question. Can you please guide me based on it.